# How to make audioplayer play again?

Tags: iphone, ios, uiview, uiviewcontroller, avaudioplayer

I have 2 view controller and I play a music with AVAudioPlayer in the first view controller.
I go to second view controller and stop the music :

```
[audioPlayer stop];    
[UIView beginAnimations:@"Curl View" context:nil];
        [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.5];
        [UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut];
        [UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionCurlUp forView:self.view cache:YES];
        [self.view addSubview:secondController.view];
        [UIView commitAnimations];
```

When I go back to first view controller again, I want to play my music again but the code doesn't touch viewDidLoad again.
Here is my code to go back :

```
[UIView beginAnimations:@"Flipping View" context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.5];
    [UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionCurlDown forView:self.view.superview cache:YES];
    [self.view removeFromSuperview];
    [UIView commitAnimations];
```

Please share me some solutions or what the code execute after that..Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Write you play code in `viewWillAppear:` , it is called when ever your view is appeared.
`viewDidLoad:` is called only once for a view controller

**Update**
Use these line to remove your second view

```
[super viewWillAppear:animated];
UIView beginAnimations:@"Flipping View" context:nil]; 
[UIView setAnimationDuration:0.5]; 
[UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];
[UIView setAnimationDidStopSelector:@selector(animationEnded)];
[UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionCurlDown forView:self.view.superview cache:YES];
[self.view removeFromSuperview];
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

And this method will be called when view is removed

```
- (void)animationEnded{ 
    NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/BGMCover2.mp3", [[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath]]]; 
    NSError *error; audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url error:&error]; audioPlayer.numberOfLoops = -1; 
    [audioPlayer play]; 
}
```

Comment: I add void void viewWillAppear and when I'm back from secondController, compiler doesn't execute viewWillAppear. I look it too from the console and it is not touched by the compiler. Can you little more detail?

Comment: NSLog(@"View Did Appear");
 NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/BGMCover2.mp3", [[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath]]];
 NSError *error;
 audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url error:&error];
 audioPlayer.numberOfLoops = -1;
 [audioPlayer play];

Comment: please write the whole method including method name and one more are you pushing or presenting 2nd view controller???

Comment: This is my viewDidAppear method : 
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
 NSLog(@"View Did Appear");
 NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/BGMCover2.mp3", [[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath]]];
 NSError *error;
 audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url error:&error];
 audioPlayer.numberOfLoops = -1;
 [audioPlayer play];
}

Comment: @AlexMoskalev call as i have shown below inside the 
-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated{
 [super viewDidAppear:YES];
 NSLog(@"View Did Appear"); NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/BGMCover2.mp3", [[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath]]]; NSError *error; audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url error:&error]; audioPlayer.numberOfLoops = -1; [audioPlayer play];

}

Comment: This is my method in secondController for back to first view controller :


UIView beginAnimations:@"Flipping View" context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.5];
    [UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionCurlDown forView:self.view.superview cache:YES];
    [self.view removeFromSuperview];
    [UIView commitAnimations];

Comment: @AlexMoskalev As you are animating view not pushing or presenting model so in that case no delegate methods are called such as `viewWillAppear:` or `viewDidAppear:`

Comment: @Kamarshad Ow....still doesn't work.
Waw I'm still struggling with that..Haha...Do you know what's wrong Kamarshad??

Comment: @InderKumarRathore Where and what should I put delegate??
I'm sorry still beginner with that

Answer (score 1):

This is happens Only because of you are calling your Music Playing code from `viewDidLoad`
And `viewDidLoad` method calls Only One time For `ViewController`.

You should Call your code(Playing Music) from `viewWillAppear` instead of `viewDidLoad` method.

[I  suggest you should read `UIViewControler` Documentation.](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

**Updated Answer**:As you want to Play the Music File at the time of loading and Coming back to View .
There may some problem regarding the Performance.
Because you calls the Music file immediately loading time of view.
So View below Lines of explaination.

- **ViewDidLoad** - This method is called after the view controller has loaded its view hierarchy into memory. This method is called regardless of whether the view hierarchy was loaded from a nib file or created programmatically in the loadView method. You usually override this method to perform additional initialization on views that were loaded from nib files.
- **ViewWillAppear:When** this gets called, it means that the iPhone is already ready to show the UIView to the user, and anything heavy you do here will impact performance in a very visible manner (like animations being delayed,or playing music etc).
- **ViewDidAppear**: Finally,This Notifies the view controller that its view was added to a view hierarchy.so this method is good enough for such task Like for example playing music file.Note-->you must call `super` at some point in your implementation.

Comment: I add void void viewDidAppear and when I'm back from secondController, compiler doesn't execute viewDidAppear. I look it too from the console and it is not touched by the compiler. Can you little more detail?

Comment: @Alex Moskalev did you call `super` in that(ViewDidAppear) method . you must call `super` at some point in your implementation.

Comment: I add [super viewDidAppear:YES] before [UIView commitAnimations] in the secondController but still it doesn't work. What I'm doing wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

Before doing your application please get deep knowledge of UIViewController life cycle. You can follow the following link :
[UIViewController Life Cycle](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html)